# Error: option clash for package glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I need to use `glossaries`, so I took an example putted in a new file and compiled using texworks and it worked fine. Now I'm trying to include the glossary in my own file and it spits out the error in the title of this question... I suspect is an inclusion package problem... so the included packages are:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package
```

What could be the problem?

Update... since the class is "homemade", i can assure you that without the glossaries it works fine. I think more relevant info are here:

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{helvet}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[british]{isodate}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{glossaries}
```

Comment: This code - snippet will not show anything but it's working. It depends possible on the class, but you've haven't provided the name of the class

Comment: The class is my own class, so i think it could be helpful understand the required packages by the class, isn't? (i can't show all the content of the class... sorry, just tell me the relevant info).

Comment: Consider the fact that your own class could be cause ;-)

Comment: The error message shows that glossaries is being loaded twice so the solution is to remove the second `\usepackage[...]{glossaries}` (or probably better here  remove the `\RequirePackage{glossaries}` from the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
\RequirePackage{glossaries}
```

from the class file, this is pre-loading `glossaries` with no options specified, which means the attempt to load it later in the preamble with options is an error.

It is generally a bad idea for a class to force hidden options on a package that is commonly loaded with options, one often sees

```
\Requirepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

or

```
\RequirePackage[dvips]{graphicx}
```

in local class files with the same bad result that any natural attempt to load these packages with different options in a document will fail with an option clash error.